# Kibana fails to recognize field is a geo_point

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, geopoints

I'm using Elasticsearch and Kibana for the first time. I have an index "q4", with type "tweet" which contains Twitter data. I want to map these tweets onto a Kibana Tile Map visualization, so I have added a geo_point property "location" to the mapping of the tweets. However, when I attempt to read this data in Kibana, I get the following message:

```
No Compatible Fields: The "q4" index pattern does not contain any of the 
following field types: geo_point
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, as the mapping of index data seems to match the documentation.

Below is the mapping of my index:

```
{u'q4': {
    u'mappings': {
        u'tweet': {
            u'properties': {
                ...(a bunch of irrelevant properties here)...
                u'location': {
                    u'type': u'geo_point'},
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My geo_points are currently represented as a comma-separated string - some example values are `41.1751247162,73.965773519` and `33.0732112811,111.596972035`. Kibana recognizes these points as strings, but not as geo_points.

I am using the below links as reference for ES geo_points and Kibana visualizations.

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-map-user-location-with-geoip-and-elk-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana

Another SO question seems to cover a similar issue, but that situation involved the use of Logstash. I am not using Logstash in my application - rather, I am sending the tweets directly to ElasticSearch using Python's Elasticsearch API wrapper library.

- [ELK - Kibana doesn't recognize geo_point field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747137/elk-kibana-doesnt-recognize-geo-point-field)

Comment: Try to look at management tab, and look at location field, does it Geo point? I guess not, try to delete the index pattern and create it again

Comment: I deleted the index pattern and reinstalled Elasticsearch. Now, everything magically works without any code changes. Still not sure why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: You probably create the index pattern when the location was string, then you reindex with the right mapping, but you forgot to refresh the index pattern